# OpenStreetMap Is it possible to make sea and land to separated layers?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap, layer

It sounds weird, I know. Anyways, I rarely say "No" until I am sure that it is not impossible. I went around on Google and StackOverflow and there are none of solution for that.

I want to split the sea water and country land into seperated layers so that I can put something in between. I attached the image for clearer explanination. Is it possible to add such green arrows in Open Street Map??

Thank you for reading my question.

[Is it possible to add such green arrows in Open Street Map as this image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV3Uw.png)

Comment: If you plan to render your own tiles then this is possible of course.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

The big concept you have to keep in mind is that OpenStreetMap is a **database**, not the rendered map images you see in www.osm.org.

What you probably want to do is to take some [OSM coastline data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline), preferably the [curated, topological-error-free files](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines), and render them into map tiles yourself. There are [a lot of different ways to render OSM data into images](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering). And depending on your scenario you might be better off using some simple [Natural Earth coastline datasets](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-coastline/).

You might also be able to use some vector-tile-based rendering engines to do this (mapbox's mapbox-gl, and mapzen's tangram come to mind) without rendering raster images at all.

---

Yes, it is possible. No, it's not completely straightforward. No, there is no "best solution", and you'll need to do extra research to see which method/tool/framework/workflow fits best with your particular use case and architecture.

Comment: thank you very much! Basically, I create a new layer which is overlapped the current land right? I am using Leaflet. Is there any way to "split" the current land to another layer?

Comment: Render your arrows, then render the landmass on top. As I've said, there is a multitude of methods to achieve this, but they will all require going lower level than Leaflet.